# RewriteRule for .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this rule in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Output:

```
http://domain.tld/username
```

Desired output:

```
http://domain.tld/user/username
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Input is http:// domain.tld/user.php?username=bob, output is http:// domain.tld/user/bob ? Or other way around?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to change a URL with a query string to a path:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*username=([a-zA-Z]+).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user/%1? [L]
```

Input

```
http://domain.tld/user.php?username=bob
```

Output

```
http://domain.tld/user/bob
```

---

Here is how to go the other way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/user/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)$ /user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

Input

```
http://domain.tld/user/bob
```

Output

```
http://domain.tld/user.php?username=bob
```

---

You can test `.htaccess` rules here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ user.php?username=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: Comment out `Options` line and retest.

Comment: Can you help me one more time? It does not load images and styles there, need I to add ../ everywhere ??

Comment: That is due to your use of relative paths. Just insert `<base href="/">` in the `<head>` section of your HTML to fix this.